# Set AKS ConfigMap data for different environment using CICD pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-aks, cicd

I am deploying asp.net core application to AKS using Azure CICD pipeline.

I am copying below configMap deployment file from bild and use in release pipeline.

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: akscicddemo-config
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "AppSettings": {
        "Env": "prod"
        }
    }
```

Now i want to update above file data with Pipeline Variable.
How can we update **data** in configMap file using release variable based on different environment (stages in pipeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **Replace Tokens** in CICD pipeline to replace specific keys from my config.yml file.

Updated Yml file

```
  apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: akscicddemo-config
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "AppSettings": {
        "Env": "#{Env}#"
        }
    }
```

[image: Replace Tokens Task]

[image: Variable in pipeline]